# Running Task In The Background

Tags: server-side, serverside-javascript, server-side-scripting

What is the technology which allows the web application to process the task in the background without holding user to wait until the task to finish.

```
Example, as a user,

 1. I want to submit a form which requires heavy processing. (Assume it requires to checking or actions, upload documentation or etc)

 2.   After submitting the form, the task will be running in the background, then I can go to other page and do something else.

    2.1   At the same time, I might submit another form to the server.
          The request can be process at the same time or can be queue under a queue system

 3. I will receive a notification from the system whenever the server return a response. (Regardless it is success or failure)
```

This feature is similar to Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: this has nothing to do with vue, react, vuex, or any of the other tags. This is a backend question and has nothing to do with the front-end specifically, as long as you request that you should be able to browse to another page.

Comment: Thank you for those people who downvote my question. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try [Kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) or any other similar libraries. The term to "google" is "[language] task queue"

You can of course roll your own. Though it will be much easier if you make use of an existing server such as redis or rabbitmq. So that queuing part is handled for you by the server and you could concentrate on your business logic.

Comment: So basically, the way to achieve this is to use the queue system?

Comment: That's most scalable way. There are simple queue implementations using just threads, but they are not as resilient.